# a error "org.apache.spark.internal.config.package" when using ./pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I download the spart-2.2, but when I run it. it's throw an error (info: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.internal.config.package).Not is Hadoop lib reason.

My OS is Linux, using JDK8, and follows the logs:

17/08/07 06:13:29 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext

> is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This
>   may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in
>   this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py",
>   line 54, in 
>       spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()   File "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py",
>   line 169, in getOrCreate
>       sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)   File "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py",
>   line 334, in getOrCreate
>       SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())   File "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py",
>   line 118, in **init**
>       conf, jsc, profiler_cls)   File "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py",
>   line 180, in _do_init
>       self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)   File
>   "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py",
>   line 273, in _initialize_context
>       return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)   File "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1401, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/home/soft/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling
>   None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. :
>   **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class**
>   org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:546)  at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:373)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)     at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)     at
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
>     at
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
>     at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)